# Why is a certain subset not a subspace of $\mathbb{K}_2$?

Tags: vector-spaces

I'm studying the module Algebra, and was reading the course book "*Álgebra. Aplicaciones a Teoría de Códigos*". I got stuck on this problem because why would a line $(y=1)$ not be a subspace of $\mathbb{K}_2$?

**Question:** Let $H=\left\{(2a,1)∣a\in \mathbb{K} \right\}$. Determine if $H$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{K}_2$, where $\mathbb{K}$ is a field.

**Answer:** As the second coordinate, considering it is $y$, is always $1$, it is not a subspace of $\mathbb{K}_2$.

**Remarks:** I tried to demonstrate that $H$ was a subspace by saying that you could factor out $a$ out of the pair $(2a,1)$, where you get $a(2,a^{-1}),a \in \mathbb{K}$.

Therefore, $H$ *seemed to be* a subspace of $\mathbb{K}_2$, except in the point $a=0$. This means $H$ could be a subspace of $\mathbb{K}_2^*$, and $a \in \mathbb{K}^*$.

Furthermore, as it is a line of the form $y=1$, this means it is not actually a subspace of any field but rather an affine space of $\mathbb{K}_2^*$ where $a \in \mathbb{K}^*$.

Moreover, as the pair $(2a,1)$ is of the form $(2a,0) + (0,1)$, if we tried to get a basis of $H$, we could take the vector $B_H=[(1,0)]$, for example, as in this case we took $a=\frac{1}{2} \neq 0$, and the translation vector would be $v_T=(0,1)$, as we previously mentioned that it is a line of the form $y=1$.

Finally, $H \subset \mathbb{K}_2$ and is an affine vector space of the form $B_H=[(1,0)]$ and $v_T=(0,1)$ .

Comment: This is not clear.  What's $y$?  And subspace of what?  What's $\mathbb K$?  If it's field, then saying $\frac 1a\in \mathbb K$ just means $a\neq 0$, right?

Comment: @lulu $y$ is the vector $(0,1)$. H is a subspace of $\mathbb{K}_2$. $\mathbb{K}$ is a field.

Comment: This makes no sense.  $H$ is only one dimensional, hence isn't in $\mathbb K^2$.  And you said that "$y=1$ always" so how is that compatible with $y=(0,1)$?

Comment: @lulu But $T=\left\{ 2a,-2a/a\in \mathbb{K} \right\}$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{K}_2$ and it is one dimensional too, right? Moreover, I am not saying it is in $\mathbb{K}_2$, I am saying it is a subspace of said field.

Comment: Do you mean $H = \{(2a, 1) \mid a \in \mathbb{K}\}$?

Comment: Did you possibly mean to write $H=\{\left(2a, \frac 1a\right)\,|\,a\in \mathbb K\}$?  That's very different from what you actually wrote.

Comment: @noam.szyfer Yes, I meant to write that subspace.

Comment: Ok, that's better.  But then $(0,0)\not \in H$ so $H$ can't be a subspace.

Comment: @lulu True that, hadn't considered such remark, thank you.

Comment: @lulu To my understanding, it is not considered a subspace, however, could it be considered an affine subspace, being k=1 the "affine number"? (The difference between it being a subspace and an affine subspace)

Comment: Yes, it is an affine space.  But a "subspace" of a vector space has a precise meaning, and $H$ does not satisfy that.

Comment: @lulu One question: I haven't understood what you meant by "What's $y$?", is $y=H(x)$ or $y=1=(0,1)\equiv \overrightarrow{j}$? If we take out $a$ as a common factor: $(2a,1)$ transforms to $a(2,a^{-1})$, so is the base of this space $B=[(2,0),(0,1/1)]$ ?

Comment: There is no $y$ in your statement.  I am guessing that you meant "as the second coordinate of the pair $(2a,1)$ is always $1$ ..." but it's better to spell that out.

Comment: @lulu So should I edit the answer as:

As the second coordinate of the pair $(2a,1)$ is always 1, it is not a subspace of $\mathbb{K}_2$ but rather an affine space of $\mathbb{K}_2$ where the base is $B=[(2,0),(0,1)]$?

Comment: It seems that the pair $(2a,1)$ is the same as saying $(2a,0)+1$, or am I wrong?

Comment: For an affine subspace, "basis" means something other than it means for a vector subspace.  $H$, here, is one dimensional (trusting that the characteristic of $\mathbb K$ is not $2$).  I'd say a basis for $H$ was $(1,0)$  with a translation vector given by $(0,1)$.  That means that every element in $H$ can be written uniquely in the form $a(1,0)+(0,1)$ for some $a\in \mathbb K$ and that, conversely, every such expression is in $H$.  Note that in characteristic other than $2$, the $2$ in the definition of $H$ has little meaning as you can divide by it.

Comment: Note that $(2a,0)$ can't be a basis vector as $a$ is not defined.

Comment: @lulu Isn't $a$ defined as $a \in \mathbb{K}$? I guess you mean we would have to define it as $a \in \mathbb{R}$, for example.

Comment: Well, you could ask to fix a value for $a$ now, but in your post $a$ was an unspecified field element.  Better to just use $1$.

Comment: So shall we define $a \in \mathbb{K}$ saying that the basis is $B=[(0,1)]$ with a translation vector given by $(0,1)$ which is the reason it is in affine space with $k=1$, being $k$ the affine constant? (Meaning that we could simplify the statement to the basis is $B=[(0,1)]$ with $k=1$)

Comment: No, $a$ is not in $\mathbb R$....$a$ is an element of your field $\mathbb K$. And the basis can't be $(0,1)$.  I chose $(1,0)$ as the basis.  You could also choose $(-1,0)$ or $(2,0)$ or indeed $(\lambda, 0)$ for any element $\lambda\in \mathbb K^*$.  I picked $1$ because we're sure that $1\in \mathbb K^*$.

Comment: Oh, ok, understood. So could we define the basis as $B=[(\lambda,0)], \forall \lambda \in \mathbb{K}^* $, where in this case $\lambda = 1$ which means that every element in H can be written uniquely in the form $a(1,0)+(0,1$) for some $a \in \mathbb{K}$?

Comment: No.  Again, to specify a basis for an affine space of dimension $1$ you need *two* vectors.  A translation vector, and a basis for the linear subspace you get when you translate the affine one so it includes the origin.  Here, if we take the translation vector to be $(0,1)$ we need a basis of the linear subspace $(2a,0)$ for $a\in \mathbb K$.  I picked $(1,0)$ as a convenient basis vector (again, assuming that the characteristic is not $2$.  But whatever you pick, it must be a specified vector.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to say "$\forall\,\lambda \in \mathbb K$ where $\lambda =1$" .  Just say $(1,0)$.

Comment: Oh ok, so the basis would be $B_H=[(1,0)]$, for example, and the translation vector would be $v_T=(0,1)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But then $(0,0)∉ H$ so $H$ can't be a subspace. [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4720995/why-is-a-certain-subset-not-a-subspace#comment10001409_4720995)

> Yes, it is an affine space. But a "subspace" of a vector space has a precise meaning, and $H$ does not satisfy that. [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4720995/why-is-a-certain-subset-not-a-subspace-of-mathbbk-2/4721011#comment10001429_4720995)

> To specify a basis for an affine space of dimension $1$ you need two vectors. A translation vector, and a basis for the linear subspace you get when you translate the affine one so it includes the origin. Here, if we take the translation vector to be $(0,1)$ we need a basis of the linear subspace $(2a,0)$ for $a \in \mathbb{K}$. I picked $(1,0)$ as a convenient basis vector (again, assuming that the characteristic is not $2$. But whatever you pick, it must be a specified vector.)  [3](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4720995/why-is-a-certain-subset-not-a-subspace/4721011#comment10001758_4720995)

As the second coordinate of the pair $(2a,1)$ is always $1$, it is not a subspace of $\mathbb{K}_2$ but rather an affine space of $\mathbb{K}_2$ where the base is $B_H=[(1,0)]$ and the translation vector is $v_T=(0,1)$.

Helped by: [lulu](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4720995/why-is-a-certain-subset-not-a-subspace#comment10001409_4720995), [lulu](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4720995/why-is-a-certain-subset-not-a-subspace-of-mathbbk-2/4721011#comment10001429_4720995), [lulu](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4720995/why-is-a-certain-subset-not-a-subspace/4721011#comment10001758_4720995).

Comment: That same answer appeared in comments about 45 minutes before your answer here.

Comment: @coffeemath True that, so how can I credit said comment?

Comment: Maybe cite @lulu's comment saying what you said...

Comment: @coffeemath Is it correct how I did it now?

Comment: Yes it is OK now.

Comment: @coffeemath there is no need to make a reference to comments. Comments should not answer question. It seems that lulu has removed some of the comments and now the links point to non existing comments

Comment: @miracle173 So what should I do?

Comment: @AntonioDeAngelis It's great that you write an answer and it is not necessary to reference any comments, But if you do so, it is fine, too.

Comment: @miracle173 Understood, thank you!